# converting a php line to twig

Tags: php, twig, opencart

Hi so I have this php code:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Showing urns for a <?php echo $person_or_animal; if( $ashes_size=='small' ){ echo ' that holds a small amount of ashes.'; }else{ echo ' '.$pp_weight; ?> cubic inches and larger. <?php } ?> <a href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>">Start over?</a></p>
```

which I converted to twig like this:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Showing urns for a {{ person_or_animal }} {% if ashes_size is 'small' %} {{ ' that holds a small amount of ashes.' }} {% endif %}{% else %}  {{ ' '~pp_weight }} cubic inches and larger. <a href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>">Start over?</a></p>
```

But when I access the page I get this:

> Fatal error: 'Unexpected token "string" of value "small" ("name"
> expected) in "default/template/extension/module/urnfindersearch.twig"
> at line 12.'

any idea the reason why this could be happening? as I am not a twig expert so if someone could help me that would be great.

Thanks
Aaron

Comment: `{% if ashes_size === 'small' %}` ??

Comment: Thanks for that :), it did help me get that section working in right direction it was == but problem i have now is:

`{% if ( in_array(id, cats) ) %} {{ 'checked' }}{% endif %}` i get:

Fatal error: 'Unknown "in_array" function in "default/template/extension/module/urnfindersearch.twig" at line 22.' 

the php for this line is: `<?php if( in_array($id, $cats) ) echo 'checked'; ?>`

Comment: Please start with reading the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html). It's all in there

Comment: Thanks for your posts :) i managed to solve it by doing:  {% if id in cats %}  :).